# How do I run localhost websites (PHP, ASP) without running the Webmatrix first

Tags: localhost, webmatrix

I am developing website using webmatrix 3 on my localhost. All works fine, if I open webmatrix and then use the Run button in the left upper corner to start the website.

However, I would like to be able to run the website even if I do not run webmatrix first. In this case I get an error "Unable to connect". What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to copy the website folder to C:/inetpub/wwwroot and now it is working. Because webmatrix websites are stored in My Documents/My Websites folder. It has to be something with folder setup and security, but I do not know what. So what I am doing now is to copy development folder to production folder after every update. Would like to skip this step, but don't know how.